# Iterating through an array and checking each item, printing error if no match

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop set up that iterates through each item in an array of objects. I have an if statement that checks to see if the values in a certain item matches a specific string value. If it does, I want to print that to the screen. I have no problem doing this. However, if the loop makes it all the way through without finding a match, I want the program to print an error message. The way I have it set up now as an if else statement, the program is printing an error message for each item if it does not match. I can't figure out a way to only do that once the loop has finished. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Set a `boolean matchFound` to false before the loop, set it to true if you find something, and print error message if it is false after the loop.

Comment: @Keppil Can you please make that an answer so that it can be upvoted and (possibly) accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern in your code:

```
boolean matchFound = false;
for (item: objects) {
    if (item.equals(stringValue) {
        //print item the same way as you did
        matchFound = true;
    }
}
if (!matchFound) {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

Comment: Ironic how our answers so similar that they end up looking like I copied you :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable to store whether or not a match has been found.  Set it false before the loop runs, and then make it true if a match is found in the loop.  If it is still false after the loop is finished, then print the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean matchFound = false; // dont be so eager that there is a match
for(String each : lotOfStrings){
    if(each.equals(someOtherStrings)){
        matchFound = true;
        // break; // optionally, you may break out
    }
}

if(!matchFound){ // no match found?
    System.out.println("Error");
}else{
    System.out.println("Found a match");    
}
```

The code snippet above shows how you might achieve what you want.

*Based on Keppil's comment*

Answer (score 0):

As Keppil suggested, a little bit optimized:

```
boolean matchFound = false;
for (int i = start; i < max && boolean == false; i++) {
    if (foundElement()) {
        matchFound = true;
    }
}
if (!matchFound) {  
    log.error = "";
}
```

or you can do

```
int i = start;
for (; i < max; i++) {
    if (foundElement()) {
        break;
    }
}
if (i == max) {
    log.error = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keppil and Little Child have good solutions, but let me suggest a refactoring that makes this problem a bit more tractable as your specifications change.  Perhaps overkill.  Break up the steps of the algorithm.  *First*, obtain a List of matches.  *Then*, decide what to do with them.  e.g.  (you'd eventually want to break up this code as well)

```
ArrayList<T> matches = new ArrayList<T>;   // T is your object type, e.g. String
for (T item : myObjects) {
   if (item.equals(thingToMatch))
      matches.add(item);
}
```

// now, decide what to do with the list...

```
if (matches.size() > 0) {
   for (T t : matches)
      // print it here
      // but in the future could log them, store in a database, convert to XML, etc...
}
else
   System.out.println("no matches were found to " + thingToMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the specific objects which match, then the cleanest way to take care of your concern is by writing a helper method which does the finding. This way we can avoid the assignment and reassignment of a local variable and the code becomes quite a bit cleaner:

```
boolean find(List<?> list, Object toFind) {
   for (Object o : list) if (o.equals(toFind)) return true;
   return false;
}
```

This works against a list of strings, as well as any other objects. In the main method you can write

```
System.out.println((find(list, toFind)? "A" : "No") + " match was found");
```

If you do need all the matching objects, then I would again recommend a helper method which returns a list of all matches, for you to print or handle any other way:

```
<T> List<T> getMatches(List<T> list, Object toFind) {
   final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>();
   for (T x : list) if (t.equals(toFind)) ret.add(x);
   return ret;
}
```

Now, in the calling method, you can have

```
final List<MyType> matches = find(inputList, toFind);
if (matches.isEmpty()) System.out.println("No match was found");
else { ... process the list as needed ... }
```